# Taking derivatives of exponential function

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Beware, this question might be silly and may contain mathematical fallacies.

$$
d/dt(e^{jwt}) = jwe^{jwt}
$$
$$
d/dt(e^{j \pi t}) = j \pi e^{j \pi t}
$$
$$
d/dt(e^{j 180 t}) = j 180 e^{j 180 t}
$$

In the second equation $\pi$ is in radians and in the third one 180 is in degrees. These two equations' derivatives must give the same results since they're the same. So are the units of these angles conserved when we take derivatives? In other words are the 180 and $\pi$ at the right hand sides of equations just numbers or numbers with units? Because otherwise the results seem different.

Comment: $180\ne \pi$.  $180^\circ = \pi$.  In other words, your last expression would read "${d\over dt}(e^{j180^\circ t})=j180^\circ e^{j180^\circ t}$"  This is usually avoided because $\pi \over 2$ is often both less writing and less potentially confusing than $90^\circ$.

Comment: @abiessu $180°\ne\pi$. $180°=\pi$ radians.

Comment: And similarly, $\pi$ is less writing and less potentially confusing than $180^\circ$. @Did: true...  but I think the radians unit of measure is often equated with adimensionality...

Comment: @abiessu so $d/dt(e^{j180°t})$ have degrees as a unit?

Comment: No, I wrote it that way to demonstrate what your statement should say given what you intend.  But writing $180^\circ$ outside of an angular context requires a definition of what that angle will mean, and typically the angle is converted to radians where it can then be treated as a dimensionless value.

Comment: This conversion is used because radians exactly match the real perimeter length of a circle, where angles in degrees have no meaning outside the $1\over 360$ proportion of the circle.

Comment: @abiessu Sorry to say so but you might simply have spread some more confusion.

Comment: @Did: I am afraid you might be right...  Would you mind putting some more detail in your answer to clear it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the second equation pi is in radians and in the third one 180 is in degrees.

No they are not, both are dimensionless numbers.

**Edit:** Let $R$ denote a radius measured in meters, then the area of the disk of radius $R$ measured in square meters is $A=\pi R^2$. What is the unit of $\pi$? Well, $\pi=A/R^2$, the unit of $A$ is the square meter, the unit of $R^2$ is the square meter, hence...

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Sure. Which part?

Comment: When I wrote $e^{j \pi t}$ the unit of pi is radians(or other degree unit) right? Otherwise sine and cosine wouldn't be defined? So when I take the derivative as $j \pi e^{j \pi t}$ is the pi at the left is adimensional, is it just the number 3.14..?

Comment: No. The unit of pi is not in radians, pi has no unit, pi is a number between 3 and 4. Would you say 3 and 4 have units? (I thought my answer was saying exactly that.)

Comment: Sine and cosine are defined equally by the ratios within a right triangle due to the other angles, or by their infinite sum forms.  We allow angles in degrees to have meaning within the context of sine and cosine, but we have exact calculations that use real numbers to actually obtain the values.  This is why the conversion to radians is necessary within most programming languages (for example).

Answer (score 1):

$\pi$ is not equal to 180.    ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Try your reasoning on this one:  My desk is 8 feet long.  It's also 96 inches long.  If I take the derivative of $x^8$, I get $8x^7$.  If I take the derivative of $x^{96}$, I get $96x^{95}$.  How can this be?

Comment: Yes I know, I just didn't knew how to make ° sign. So is the 180 which is at left of the right hand side of the third equation, is that 180 is in degrees?

Comment: @baris_ercan: yes, that $180$ would be $180^\circ$, just like in WillO's answer he would actually have $x^{8'},8'x^{8'-1}$ and $x^{96"},96"x^{96"-1}$, but these formulas require meaning for the quantities $8'-1$ and $96"-1$ ("eight feet minus real-number 1" and "96 inches minus real-number 1").